# PHP mailer issue (mail dont come)

Tags: php, email, gmail

Hello I am trying to create an email confirmation script but i cant even send an email from a simple php script I create I don't really know what is going wrong

```
$from = 'anothermail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'body';
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// send mail
if (mail("my-mail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n")){
echo "It works";
}
else{

echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: $from should also be a string

$from = 'anothermail@gmail.com';

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$from = 'anothermail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'body';
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// send mail
if (mail("my-mail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: ".$form."\n")){
echo "It works";
}
else{

echo "Fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> $from = 'anothermail@gmail.com'; 
>   $subject = 'test';
>   $message = 'body';
>   $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
>   $headers = "From: $from \r\n". 
>                 "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
>                 "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
>   // send mail
>   if (mail("my-mail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$headers)){
>   echo "It works";
>   }
>   else{
>   echo "Fail";
>   }

Comment: again the same problem

Comment: Do you have root access to your server or using cpanel? Try this print_r(error_get_last()) for getting the error when mail() returns false.If its not working do check with your hosting provider